# Is there any way to call a specific element without using class or id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm trying to manipulate all my HTML tags this code.
I listed them like so:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

And I would like to manipulate the variable
`elements` and modify the tags in it.

Thing is, I need to add an ID or some sort of class on all of them.

Is there any way other than having to add an id or classname?
Is there any special id given to the tags by default or something?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
I use data-id usage to manipulate the elements. So... now my code looks like this:

```js
const dataIDName = "data-spellchecker"

//Init the data-id
noOfElements++;
elements[i].setAttribute(dataIDName, noOfElements);
```

```js
//Get the DOM element by data-id variable

//dataId is ur data-id variable
document.querySelector(`[${dataIDName}="${dataId}"]`);
```

Comment: "I need to add an ID or some sort of class on all of them". What for? How would you use the ID or class if you had it?

Comment: `"*"` is not a specific element, in the context of `document` it includes all the elements within the document, also `<html>` root element and all the elements in the head section.

Comment: I'm not sure but i would give them special names like class1, class2,... and iterate on each one of them and use them like taht but yeah, I know that's not a good way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to make a spell checker extension, that's why I need all tags except <html> and <js> and show the errors by using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign **data-id** and a value to it

you can access it in jquery using

```
const value = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-id')
```

example:

```
<button class="submitButton" id="btn1" data-id="1">Submit</Button>
```

Comment: I didn't know about data-id, thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the elements mainly based on:

1. Id
2. Class
3. Name
4. Tagname

Also, use xpaths with your own logic.